# Why can I hear this beep at 6 kHz and others cannot?

Tags: frequency, human, beeps

During a studio recording, I heard a beep and paused the recording. I played it back and neither the actress, sound technician, or assistant director could hear it. I imagined that it could be the remote control unit of the air conditioning, which was turned off but still listening.

Listening to the tapes, I heard it again and found it in the frequency spectrum:

[image: frequency spectrum]

It is very, very faint, so here is the same picture with gamma correction and a note on the beep:

[image: frequency spectrum, adjusted]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/85klg21f9ljibbv/beep.wav?dl=0) is the recording.

I asked a musician and he didn't hear it either. I did frequency repair and it almost worked; doing it on the voice as well made it sound tinny. If I delete all frequencies above 6k, the voice sounds muffled; if I delete frequencies below, the voice becomes unintelligible. At 6k, it should be well within [the frequency range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_hearing#Frequency_range) of a human ear:

> Frequencies capable of being heard by humans are called audio or sonic. The
> range is typically considered to be between 20 Hz and 20,000 Hz.

Why can I hear this beep sound and several people cannot?

Comment: Are you member of the K-9 family?

Comment: @AlaskaMan What is the K-9 family?

Comment: k-9 is American slang for 'canine' i.e. a dog.

Comment: Lol! No, I'm a real human curious about a newly discovered ability. That also explains trouble sleeping at night...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I listened to the file several times and couldn't hear it. In a spectrum analyzer, I can see what you're referring to. It's at -90 dB, so you'd have to crank up the volume pretty far to be able to hear it.

Because the speech volume in the recording is at -20 dB, most people will set the volume to a level where that's comfortable to listen to, and the beep will disappear below the noise floor.

The spectrum indicates the sound is in a narrow frequency band (or even a single frequency), so you might be able to get rid of it with a very narrow notch filter.

[image]

Comment: Can you hear it if you increase the volume on that part only? I am also able to notice other background rumble when listening with volume at level comfortable for me and others cannot; does that simply mean that I have more sensitivity to background noise?

Comment: Yes. I can also hear it if I listen to the unedited recording on my IEMs with the volume a bit above normal (doing this on my laptop, so can't say how much above normal).

Comment: It's entirely possible your hearing is more sensitive than others. You're probably also more used to how the studio and its equipment sounds than the others.

Comment: Thanks. This was my first time recording in studio. I was bothered by it and stopped recordings, so I got good alternate tape anyway.