# Is this blip due to the voice actor or the recording equipment?

Tags: recording, bugs

I am starting direction and audio production. In my recordings with a Sennheiser MD 441 dynamic microphone, I often hear a blip and I wonder if it's due to the voice actors or to the recording equipment. I notice it often at the end of a sentence, and sometimes during silences. I may not notice it during text because it's covered by the much louder actor's voice. In the time domain with dB, it's this little peak at the right:

[image: blip]

You can hear the blip [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7jn61ivk7odm4k9/blip.mp3?dl=0) and another occurrence [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jf28bx7i1qh8mtj/blip2.mp3?dl=0). It's subtle and I think only a few people would hear it; still, it's bugging me and I'd rather avoid it during recordings.

The regularity at the end of sentences could point towards the actors. Yet, I suspect it's from the equipment because it happens with two voice actors on different days.

What is the blip, and does it come from the actor or the recording equipment?

**Update**: Compared to [Why can I hear this beep at 6 kHz and others cannot?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/48651/why-can-i-hear-this-beep-at-6-khz-and-others-cannot) (which I asked, and suggested by @audionuma in the comments): that beep was definitely electronic, probably from the sleeping infrared receiver of the air conditioning unit in the room. This blip is different: shorter, louder, and with a regular occurrence at end of sentences. I'd like to know if it's from the equipment, and thus find another studio, or from the actor, and thus talk to the actor about how to avoid it.

**Second update**: I have similar blips with a different computer, microphone, and voice actor. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fizepebkxdylgy8/home%20recording%20blip.wav?dl=0) is one with a Samson C01U condenser microphone and a MacBook, with no sound processing, in a home studio. It has two cracks between "ga" and "do" at a time when the home studio and the actor were otherwise silent and motionless.

I find curious that these blips come in both a dynamic and a condenser microphone. They are driving me crazy and taking dozens of hours to edit them out, so I appreciate any help to avoid them in future recordings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I hear this beep at 6 kHz and others cannot?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/48651/why-can-i-hear-this-beep-at-6-khz-and-others-cannot)

Comment: @audionuma I asked that question and got an answer. I edited the question to explain the difference.

Comment: Hav you tried recording silence, no talking? If the blip is heard then it is not from the speaker. Use the exakt same equipment and exakt same setup to make sure.

Comment: @ghellquist Recording silence for 20 seconds did not give blips. It seems a big coincidence that the same thing happens with two different actors and microphones: could it be an interaction between the voice and the equipment that causes the blip, e.g. when the voice hits a certain frequency the equipment goes into resonance?

Comment: @miguelmorin  I would guess at something in the room. Might be if you have setup a chain of effects on recording, say a compressor and a gate.

Comment: This also happens with Audacity on macOS and the Samson microphone. Do they have a chain of effects in hardware of software?